# Error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have little problem in my code, I'm sure it's nothing but I can't find it.

Someone can help me?

I get this:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zone1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#cercle2-1').fadeIn(200);
    }
    $('#zone1').mouseout(function(){
        $('#cercle2-1').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was missing two right parenthesis to close the function calls.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#zone1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#cercle2-1').fadeIn(200);
      }); //Need right paren and semi to finish statement
      $('#zone1').mouseout(function(){
        $('#cercle2-1').fadeOut(200);
      }); //Need right paren and semi to finish statement
  });
```

Comment: Thank you... What an idiot I am :)

Comment: @Clemeent Glad I could help.  Don't worry it happens to everyone, the trick is to just keep going.  Not everything happens on the first try.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Maybe you could also show OP that he can chain the methods instead og using the selector twice.

Comment: So your saying `$(select).mouseover(function(){}).mouseout(function(){});`  ??